# [Pandas, Python]; Retain Empty Columns in Space Separated Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with values like below

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
5   6 7
8     9
```

When i read the above frame into Pandas using the below

```
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw_2), sep='\s+')
```

It is read as

```
A B C   D
1 2 3   4
5 6 7   NaN
8 9 NaN NaN
```

Is there a way i can retain the blank columns and have the 9 under column D instead of B

Comment: Looks like you do not have a dataframe but have either a text table or a CSV file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reader that reads fixed-width columns:

```
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(raw_2))
#   A    B    C  D
#0  1  2.0  3.0  4
#1  5  NaN  6.0  7
#2  8  NaN  NaN  9
```

This procedure is not guaranteed to work in general. You may have to specify the columns widths by hand.

Comment: This Worked for me however to to the complexity of the data frame i had to use additional processing but this is a good suggestion thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw_2), sep=r'\s{1,2}')

    A   B   C   D
0   1   2.0 3.0 4
1   5   NaN 6.0 7
2   8   NaN NaN 9
```

Which uses the regex pattern \s{1,2} as the separator. This regex matches 1-or-2 whitespace characters.

> \s{1,2} matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>
> {1,2} Quantifier — Matches between 1 and 2 times, as many times as
>   possible, giving back as needed